# How to convert context_definitions to PHP attribute syntax?

Tags: blocks, 10

Drupal 10.2 [enables PHP attributes to be used instead of annotations](https://www.drupal.org/node/3395575).

So I tried to create some PHP attributes for one of my blocks:

```
/**
 * Provides an 'Ebook Navigation' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "ebooknavigation_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("eBook navigation block"),
 *   category = @Translation("MyModule"),
 *   context_definitions = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

This is what I came up witH:

```
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

#[Block(
  id: 'ebooknavigation_block',
  admin_label: new TranslatableMarkup('eBook navigation block'),
  category: new TranslatableMarkup('MyModule'),
)]
```

However, I don't understand how to convert the `context_definitions` part.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, only two annotation classes have been converted to attribute classes. Blocks defined by Drupal core modules still use annotations, like the [`AnnounceBlock`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.2.x/core/modules/announcements_feed/src/Plugin/Block/AnnounceBlock.php?ref_type=heads) class.

```php
/**
 * Provides an 'Announcements Feed' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "announce_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Announcements Feed"),
 * )
 *
 * @internal
 */
```

Since attributes cannot be nested in attributes, once Drupal 10.2 gets its stable release, the annotation to use should be similar to the following one.

```php
#[Block(
  id: 'ebooknavigation_block',
  admin_label: new TranslatableMarkup('eBook navigation block'),
  category: new TranslatableMarkup('MyModule'),
  context_definitions: array(new ContextDefinition("entity:node", new TranslatableMarkup("Node")))
)]
```